# Bitcoin Mainnet Initialization Crash

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoind, full-node, synchronization, cache

I am trying to initialize a fully functional working mainnet node. The initial download with
`bitcoind` works fine until the cache reaches around 600MiB. After which it crashes. The entire 600MiB is disposed of, and I need to start again. I checked debug.log, but there were no inconsistencies that could have been suggested for the occurrence of the crash. I am setting up this system on Oracle VMWare, with around 650 GB of disk space.

Is there any way by which, after 600MiB of cached data, I can flush it to disk and resume with the download again? Also, any knowledge of what is causing this problem will be helpful.

Comment: How much (available) RAM do you have? My best guess is that your node is crashing exactly when it's trying to flush to disk, at which time it temporarily uses a bit more memory.

Comment: For this machine I have allocated around 6GB.